# RSA шифрование PHP

Tags: php, xml, rsa

Всем привет задача надо xml сообщение подписанный транспортным протоколом зашифровать с помощью RSA ключом, сам ключ имеется как это реализовать PHP? подскажите пожалуйста

---

Comment: [Encrypt and Decrypt text with RSA in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484246/encrypt-and-decrypt-text-with-rsa-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Конечно имеется. Смотрите документацию [openssl_public_encrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php). Если ищите готовые решения, то смотрите в сторону [phpseclib: RSA](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/intro.html) и решения [EasyRSA](https://github.com/paragonie/EasyRSA).